# Sublime show lines with specific repeated character

Tags: sublimetext

I have a massive (400Mb) CSV file that I need to upload into a database.

The problem is that some lines contain 16 commas (",") and some 17.

I need to find the lines that contain 17 commas so that I can fix them (shouldn't be that many).

Is there a way to search in sublime so that each line becomes visible, that repeatedly contains the same particular character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for regular expressions!

[Instructions on activating regexes in Sublime Text](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)

You want the regex `(.*,){17}` - i.e., seventeen instances of any old nonsense followed by a comma.

Comment: it think this can solve my problem, but the code is not giving me the right results.

Comment: What results is it giving? Did you click the `.*` button to activate regular expression search, and then type exactly `(.*,){17}` into the search box? (That's open parenthesis, period, asterisk, comma, close parenthesis, open brace, 17, close brace)

Comment: i get the exception:
"the complexity of matching the regular expression exceeded predefined bounds"